# Would multiple RIPng processes improve convergence times and stability and larger RIP deployments

Tags: ipv6, rip

You could label this a theoretical question but I consider it a design question. 
Is is possible to have a large RipNG deployment using multiple RINng instances and 
simulate OSPF like areas?

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Areas are a feature of the link-state protocols. Areas reduce the amount of topology information each router can see and needs to process.

RIPng is a distance-vector protocol. Distance-vector routers have no topology information past their neighbors, so there is no need for Areas.

You can have a large RIPng deployment. To reduce the amount of route updates, you should use route summarization. Contrary to OSPF, you can summarize routes anywhere, not just between the Areas.